# Finding all numbers in txt filename and sum them. Python

Tags: python

I have to find all numbers in filenames of multiples txt files in a specific directory and add them. How I have to do that? :) 
I tried this code:

```
import glob, os
os.chdir("mydirectory")
for filename in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    re.findall(r"\d+", filename)
    print(filename)
re.findall(r"\d+", file)
```

but it found only the last filename numbers.

Comment: Do you want to add the numbers in the names of the files or the numbers in the file contents?

Comment: I want to all all numbers which are in the names of the files

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you done any debugging? _but it found only the last filename numbers._ That's because you're throwing away the result inside the loop.

Comment: ok, got it ! sorry, I'm new in programming so my questions may seem silly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a list and append the numbers of all files. The rest of the code you already have.

```py
import re
os.chdir("mydirectory")

numbers = []

for filename in glob.glob("*.txt"):

    # extract the numbers using regex and append in numbers list
    numbers += re.findall(r"\d+", filename)

print(numbers)

numbers = map(int, numbers) # convert strings to numbers

print(sum(numbers)) # sum them and print the values
```